# Version control for IPython notebook

Tags: python, git, svn, jupyter-notebook

Should we be committing the .ipynb_checkpoints directory into Git or SVN version control for an IPython Notebook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should not. Checkpoints are temporary snapshots of your notebooks, in case anything goes wrong (e.g. power outage, etc). This of a checkpoint as the result of saving your notebook. Do you commit each time you make a change and save your that change to disk?

Comment: I see. Thanks. I usually commit changes after I have finished an important section of my notebook.